# Implementing "create NFT" onClick using Metaplex

Tags: blockchain, solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I want to **create/upload NFTs using metaplex on button click**. I have the **metadata json file an the nft artwork** in a folder. They **have to be uploaded to candy machine in a button click**. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Best Way to do this is using the Metaplex/js SDK because in Candy Machine the metadata is stored on-chain in an account and the mint Happens in Random order So it does not guarantee you that the user pressing the button is going to get the exact same NFT. So i would suggest you use the JS [SDK](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js) it contains a function called `create` which can mint an NFT on-demand provided the metadata beforehand.

```
const { nft } = await metaplex
.nfts()
.create({
    uri: "https://arweave.net/123",
    name: "My NFT",
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500; // Represents 5.00%.
})
.run();
```

Comment: Should I upload the nft artwork and the metadata file beforehand to the storage server (arweave)? How to give the URI for the NFT?

Comment: Ya So you have to upload it before doing the Mint you can do that for the JS SDK as well

Comment: Thanks a lot Pratik! Much needed help!